# }' expected. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to use the style tag in order to make the website I'm working for, much more mobile-friendly, however, the style tag was giving me errors

```js
const styleCheck = () => {
        return (
            <div>
                <style>
                    Grid {
                        display: flex
                    }
                </style>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The idea is that Grid is a different tag that I use later on, in the return value for the main function and hence I wanted to change it's location depending on whether the user is browsing in mobile mode or on a larger screen like a laptop.

However, the program is giving me error on the `display:flex` line. It states that `}' expected` and on the } right below the line it gives the error: Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'}'}` or `&rbrace;`?

I could, of course, give more code if necessary, but I'm curious as to the reasoning for this error in the style tag.

Comment: use a string for the content of the `<style>` and enclose this string in braces.

Comment: @tromgy would it be like Grid { 'width:10px', 'height:100px'} (I changed the inner value from display to width and height but my question doesn;t change here), aka under quotes and seperated by commas?

Comment: No, what you need is to enclose everything: `<style>{'Grid { display: flex; }'}</style>`

Comment: @tromgy I see, thank you so much. Is there a reason that works like that because most of the guides I saw remove the {''}

Comment: What happens here is that the content of the `<style>` tag needs to be passed directly into the rendered HTML, so you need to "escape" it so it's not being interpreted as JSX.